# Connecting Facebook SDK to xcode/swift works, but I'm having issues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook

I was able to get the Facebook SDK on xcode and I was able to get a login button and such. Works great.

But if I try to CMD click on any of the FB things to view the source code, it says

> Couldn't Generate Swift Representation
>   Error (from SourceKit):
>   "Could not load module: FBSDKLoginKit"

Seems that something is not linked correctly, but I can't figure out what.

I figured out one of the problems I was having, but I am still having this issue with going to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two occasions when this problem might arise:

1. Your framework cannot be located.

Fix: Go to target's Build Settings and add a path to Framework Search Paths
      `/Users/<user>/path-to-framework-parent-directory`

2. Probably path to your framework contains a space in it.

Eg: change /Desktop/App Dev/NewFolder to /Desktop/AppDev/NewFolder

Even if you try to escape it with backslash ../App\ Dev/NewFolder or take the whole path in double-quotes "../App Dev/NewFolder", the SourceKit won't be able to load the module.

Answer (score 0):

Please go for pod installation. do work space creation and use the following lines.

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'
```